Unicast-mode network load balancing on Hyper-V virtual servers
I have been struggling with an issue and I hope that someone can help me. I don't know whether Hyper-V or my physical switch is misconfigured (or both are misconfigured).
I have two virtual servers, RDS1 and RDS2, running Windows Server 2022 Standard on a Hyper-V host that is also running Windows Server 2022 Standard. The four physical network interfaces on the Hyper-V host are connected to a Meraki MS350-24X Layer 3 switch. All physical network interfaces on the host are in a switch-embedded team that has SR-IOV enabled.
All four ports on the switch to which the host connects are currently configured as trunk ports with a native VLAN of 320 and with all VLANs allowed.
VLAN 320 - Servers

Subnet: 172.16.32.0/24
Switch interface address: 172.16.32.1/24

The hypervisor and all virtual servers on it have addresses in the server subnet.
I want to configure network load balancing on RDS1 and RDS2 with Network Load Balancing Manager. I wanted to use multicast routing for the NLB cluster, but I used unicast routing because multicast routing requires static ARP entries and a Meraki support representative told me, "I am unaware of any mechanism to configure a static ARP entry on an MS switch."
I have given RDS1 and RDS2 two virtual network adapters each. All four network adapters are on the same virtual switch. I created a VLAN on the Meraki switch for network load balancing.
VLAN 330 - Network load balancing

Subnet: 172.16.33.0/29
Switch interface address: 172.16.33.1/29

IP addresses

RDS1 adapter #1: 172.16.32.3/24
RDS1 adapter #2: 172.16.33.4/29 (MAC address spoofing enabled)
RDS2 adapter #1: 172.16.32.4/24
RDS2 adapter #2: 172.16.33.3/29 (MAC address spoofing enabled)
NLB cluster: 172.16.33.4/29

I am following this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/configure-virtual-local-areal-networks-for-hyper-v. If I do not follow the instruction to enable VLAN identification for the management operating system on the virtual switch, I can only reach the addresses of RDS1 adapter #2 and RDS2 adapter #2 from the virtual servers. If I enable VLAN identification for the management operating system and set the VLAN identifier to 320, I also lose my connection to the hypervisor but not to its virtual machines.


I'm not completely following your question, but I will tell you that if you want to use NLB then you have to enable MAC address spoofing on the NLB NIC on each VM. See below.


Thanks.  I've done that, but only on the adapter on each server that is used for load balancing.
I will try to summarize my issue:  I am trying to introduce a new subnet on a Hyper-V switch and a physical switch, but I can only access addresses on the new subnet (except the address of the interface on the physical switch) from other virtual machines on the same physical host.
